# JQuery Animation Cancelled By mouseout

Tags: jquery, animation, mouseover

I have a simple JQuery animation that reduces the opacity of a div on mouseover, back to 100% on mouseout, and on click moves the div down a few hundred pixels. Simple enough right?

Problem is: User clicks and it starts to move the div but if user moves mouse while its animating, a mouseout event is detected and it cancels the animation.

```
<!--MOUSEOVER ANIMATION-->

$(".roll").hover(function(){
    var rollid = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#h" + rollid).stop().animate({
    opacity: ".7"
    }, 400 );
});

$(".roll").mouseout(function(){
    var rollid = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#h" + rollid).stop().animate({
    opacity: "1"
    }, 400 );
});

<!--BUTTON CLICK-->
$(".roll").click(function(){
    $(".roll").removeClass("roll");
    var rollid = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".tbox").stop().animate({
    top: "540"
    }, 400,function(){
        $("#p1").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Page link is http://www.megadyne.com/safezone/index2.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover function can be used for hover in and out like so:

```
$(".roll").hover(function(){
    var rollid = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#h" + rollid).stop().animate({
        opacity: ".7"
    }, 400 );
}, function(){
    var rollid = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#h" + rollid).stop().animate({
        opacity: "1"
    }, 400 );
});
```

By the way you might want to change `.stop()` to `.stop(true, true)`: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Also there is the animation `fadeIn` & `fadeOut`: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/